# data in dataview is showing data in Div

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, desktop-application

I am working on a Vb.net Desktop Application Login Page, I have created database in MS Access, when i show the data in data grid view it shows my data which i have saved in database table in DIV.

Any Suggestion ...

Data saved in Database
[image]

Data show in Data Grid View
[image]

My Code is:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|hrm.accdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
               "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '" & txt_user.Text & "' AND password = '" & txt_pass.Text & "' ", conn)
    conn.Open()

    Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ' If the record can be queried, it means passing verification, then open another form.   

    If (sdr.Read() = True) Then
        Dim hrmAdminPanel As New hrmAdminPanel
        hrmAdminPanel.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid name or password!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Never concat strings to make SQL and never ever store passwords as plain text.  What is `hrmAdminPanel`?  How does the data in the reader get into the DGV?  The code shown doesnt seem to be relevant to the question

Comment: And _password_ is a reserved word in Access SQL, thus: `".. AND [password] = '" .."`.

Comment: @Plutonix hrmAdminPanel is a form which i want to load after the username and password verification.

Its a login page where user enter username and password, after verification it gets to admin panel. That admin panel name is hrmAdminPanel.

Comment: @Gustav You means that i should change the name of password input field?

Comment: No, that's up to you, but if not, brackets are needed as shown.

Answer (score 0):

The Data type of the fields were MEMO by default in MS ACCESS, i changed it to text and it resolve the problem. Now it's working perfectly fine